# Simple Terminal(ST) exit wihout error message when execute jfrog command

Tags: jfrog-cli

I met the issue when running the command line (`jfrog rt u` ) in the Simple Terminal. the terminal will exit without any error message. other commands are find

OS: Arch

WM: dwm

Terminal: ST

i just installed some of patches from the suckless website.and not sure if more patches needed

Screenshot below:

[Error when execute jfrog command.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7gJu.gif)